# Best approach to handling Post-Install script exception

Tags: managed-package, postinstall, try-catch

As inspired by [this post on when to use `try catch` blocks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295708/when-do-we-really-need-try-catch/295713?noredirect=1#comment443014_295713), if we have a post-install script for our managed package, what's the best approach to gracefully catching and handling an exception?

It seems like catching the exception is in everyone's best interest so that it doesn't prevent the installation altogether, as our post-install script is not mission-critical and manual post-install steps could be used.

I'm just hesitant to do any email sending commands just in case those email settings are turned off (like the default settings in a sandbox...), and am not sure what I can do as an ISV to have visibility on these thrown exceptions (and properly debug afterwards).