# How to cover the catch block for after insert Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, try-catch

When you create a `Barrel`, a `Filling` is also created. Is there any chance to make a fake error in unit test between `Barrel` and `Filling` to crush the upsert process and cover the `catch` block?

Helper:

```
public void insertFilling(List<Barrel__c> createdBarrels){
List<Filling__c> fillingsToInsert = new List<Filling__c>();
for(Barrel__c barrel : createdBarrels){
    if(barrel.FinishDateTime__c >= Date.TODAY()){     
        fillingsToInsert.add(
            new Filling__c(Barrel__c = barrel.Id, Barrel_ExternalID__c = barrel.Id)
        );
    }
}
if(!fillingsToInsert.isEmpty()){
    try{
        upsert fillingsToInsert Barrel_ExternalID__c;
    //I want to cover this part:
    } catch(Exception e){
        //email error notification
    }
}
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger BarrelTrigger on Barrel__c (after insert) {
  TriggerHelper helper = new TriggerHelper();
  helper.insertFilling(Trigger.new);
}
```

Test:

```
    @isTest static void testBarrelInsertException(){
    Barrel__c barrel = new Barrel__c(
        Name = 'TestBarrel',
        Opportunity__c = null, //required field
        FinishDateTime__c = DateTime.NOW().AddDays(1)
    );
    //But I even can't insert it. I'm getting the 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING' error:
    insert barrel;
    //And still no coverage.
}
```

Comment: If you ever run into a situation where you really need to cause an exception for a unit test, using dependency injection is going to be your best option (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/breaking-runtime-dependencies-with-dependency-injection.html). That way you can use a testing version of one of your dependencies to cause it to always fail or throw a specific exception.

Comment: Thank you!......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to cover a `catch` is if you cause your code inside the `try` to fail.

In your case you should get rid of the try/catch because it will never fail (or, let's say you introduce a new validation rule on the Filling it will always fail and you will need to change the trigger).

There another good answer that discuss the benefits of catching: [When do we really need try/catch?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295708/when-do-we-really-need-try-catch)