# ERROR: 'Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, after-trigger, sum

I have a trigger bellow which calculates a sum of field in a related field  in  custom object . I am getting an error massage `Variable does not exist:House_Improvements__c`. Any ideas how can I resolve the issue?
Thanks

```
trigger SumCalculations on House_Improvements__c (after insert,after update, after delete,after undelete) {
    List<id> PropertyIds = new List<id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        For(House_Improvements__c himp1 : Trigger.new){
            PropertyIds.add(himp1.Property__c);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(House_Improvements__c  himp1 : Trigger.old){
            PropertyIds.add(himp1.Property__c);
        }
    }
    List<Property__c> PropertyToUpdate = new List<Property__c>();
    decimal sum = 0;
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        For (Property__c q: [SELECT id,SUM_Calculations__c, (SELECT id, Price__c FROM House_Improvements__r) FROM Property__c WHERE id =:PropertyIds]){
            sum = 0;
            for(House_Improvements__c   p : q.House_Improvements__r)
                sum = sum + p.House_Improvements__c ;
            q.SUM_Calculations__c  = sum;
            PropertyToUpdate .add(q);
        }
        try{
            update PropertyToUpdate ;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Property__c q : [SELECT SUM_Calculations__c ,(SELECT id,Price__c FROM House_Improvements__r) FROM Property__c WHERE id =: PropertyIds]){
            sum = 0;
            for(House_Improvements__c  p : q.House_Improvements__r)
                sum = sum + p.House_Improvements__c ;
            q.SUM_Calculations__c  = sum;
           PropertyToUpdate .add(q);
        } 
        try{
            update PropertyToUpdate ;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the exact error message and line # it references. Also, do you have an object called `House_Improvements__c` with a field called `House_Improvements__c`?

Comment: KrisG is suggesting it might be the line `sum = sum + p.House_Improvements__c ;` that is causing this failure, I believe.

Comment: I would also suggest that you review [best practice around exception handling](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295708/when-do-we-really-need-try-catch/295713#295713); what you have here will likely lead to data inconsistency in the org since you allow house improvements to be inserted/updated/deleted even if you are unable to also update the property data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `List<SObject>` to a `Decimal`, so `sum = sum + p.House_Improvements__c` would fail even if you used the correct reference to the child list (`House_Improvements__r`).

**Incorrect**:

```
sum = sum + p.House_Improvements__c;
```

**Correct**

```
for (House_Improvements__c child : p.House_Improvements__r)
    sum += child.Price__c;
```

Please note, **you should always use singular object names**. Your code would be much less confusing if you had done so here. If it is not too late, rename your object to `House_Improvement__c`.

Comment: I would also add that using single character variable names is a bad practice... you might expect "p" to represent a property, but here it represented a home improvement... use an IDE for development, type the variable names to be meaningful and use the IDE's auto-completion to still keep the amount of typing to a minimum.

Comment: Totally agree with you on that point.